# Bootstrap 3 - navbar content dissappears when screen resizes - does not collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am trying to create a basic navigation bar that resizes. The collapse class should let the menu collapse itself but for some reason, when I resize the screen, the only thing visible is the header that stays active all the time. What am I doing wrong here? I tried removing classes, removing divs, and nothing seemed to be working. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this problem. Thanks!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Option 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Option 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Option 3</a>
                    </li>                
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Option 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Option 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Option 6</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Option 7</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

1. You're missing the toggle button and its descendants (see below).
2. You have `div.collapse.navbar-collapse` duplicated twice, remove the first one from the docs.
3. `div.container` is supposed to be placed directly *after* `nav.navbar-fixed-top` when using the fixed navbar.

Add the button and its contents within `.navbar-header`

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
</div> <!--/.navbar-header-->
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9pruK/2/)**